# How to find the molar mass of an iron compound based on its mass and mole fraction in the compound?

Tags: stoichiometry

I'm trying to solve this question:

> We have a molecule composed of $3$ iron atoms, and $4$ atoms of another element. We are given the following information: it has $\pu{2.36 g}$ of iron for $\pu{3.26 g}$ of molecule.

I want to find the molar mass of the compound, I have tried so far: 
$$ m = \pu{3.26 g} = \pu{0.00326 kg}$$
Since it has $3$ atoms of $\ce{Fe}$ and $4$ atoms of an unknown substance, therefore:
$$3 + 4 = 7~\text{atoms},\\
  \pu{1 mol} = \pu{6.022* 10^23 atoms}\\
\frac{7}{\pu{6.022* 10^23}} = \pu{1.16 * 10^-23}$$

As we know: $M = m / n,$ I tried to divide $0.00326$  by $\pu{1.16 * 10^-23}$ and I obtained $\pu{2.79429 * 10^19}$, but the correct answer is $\pu{231.43 g/mol}$.

What I have done wrong?

Comment: (3.26-2.36)/(2.36/55.845/3*4)*4+55.845*3

Comment: @WeijunZhou thank you but what 55.845 represent?

Comment: @napi15 The molar mass of iron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\ce Z$ denote the unknown element.
The total amount of iron atom in the compound is,

$$n(\ce{Fe})=\frac{\pu{2.36g}}{\pu{55.845 g\cdot mol^{-1}}}=\pu{0.0423 mol},$$

The molecule comprises of 3 iron atoms and 4 other atoms, so the amount of the unknown atom is,

$$n(\ce Z)=\pu{0.0423 mol}\times \frac43=\pu{0.0564 mol},$$

The molar mass of $\ce Z$ is,

$$M(\ce Z)=\frac{\pu{3.26g}-\pu{2.36g}}{\pu{0.0564 mol}}=\pu{15.97 g\cdot mol^{-1}}$$

So $\ce Z$ is $\ce{O}$. The molar mass is
$$M(\ce{Fe3O4})=\pu{55.845 g\cdot mol^{-1}}\times 3 + \pu{15.97 g\cdot mol^{-1}}\times 4=\pu{231.43 g}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Before I start explaining it, I would say that the data provided in the question and the correct answer corresponds to the compound $\ce{Fe3O4}$, whose molar mass is $\pu{231.43 g}$. But, I am not proceeding with this known fact rather I'm considering only the given data and the molar mass of iron, $\pu{55.845 g}$.

In $\pu{1 mol}$ of the compound, $\ce{Fe3X4}$, there are $\pu{3 mol}$ of $\ce{Fe}$ and $\pu{4 mol}$ of the unknown element $\ce{X}$.
Let molar mass of the compound be $M$ grams.
There is $3\times\pu{55.845 g}$ of $\ce{Fe}$ in $M$ grams of the compound.

Given, in $\pu{3.26 g}$ of the compound, $\pu{2.36 g}$ of $\ce{Fe}$ is present.
Therefore, $\pu{1 g}$ of $\ce{Fe}$ is present in $\pu{(3.26 / 2.36) g}$ of the compound.
Therefore, $3\times\pu{55.845 g}$ of $\ce{Fe}$ is present in
$(3.26 / 2.36) \times 3 \times \pu{55.845 g}$ of the compound.

Therefore, $M = (3.26 / 2.36) \times 3 \times 55.845 = 231.43$, the molar mass is $\pu{231.43g/mol}$.

Comment: The correct unit for (relative) molar mass is  $\pu{g/mol}$, you are a bit inconsistent with that. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: Yes I knew since begining it was the oxygene , but I must follow the flow of the question